# Amazon EC2 boot time

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

Our web app performs a random number of tasks for a user initiated action. We have built a small system where a master server calculates the number of worker servers that are needed to complete the task, and the same number of EC2 instances are "Turned On" which pick up the tasks and perform the same.

"Turned On" because the time taken to span an instance from an AMI is extremely high. So the idea is have a pool of worker instances and start and stop them as per requirement.

Also considering how amazon charges when you start up an instance (You are billed for 1 hour every time you Turn on an instance). The workers once spawned will be active for an hour and will accept other tasks during this period.

We have managed to get this architecture up and running, however the boot up time still bothers us as it fluctuates between 40 to 80 seconds. Is there some way we can reduce the same.

Below is the stack information of the things running on the worker instance

- Ubuntu AMI
- Node JS (using forever-service for auto startup on boot)
- Docker (the tasks are performed inside individual docker containers)

Comment: How are you defining "boot up time?"  Is time AWS takes to actually spawn the instance being included, or is this a measurement of, for example, something potentially more deterministic, like the time between when the instance starts responding to pings, and the time all of the services are ready for requests?

Comment: Since the servers already spawned, the boot up time I am referring to does not include the same. To further simplify I am referring to the time between the AWS api call to boot up a "powered off" server and the time node.js starts running.

Comment: I suspect a useful metric to observe would be the variation in "time to first ping" and then from there to service availability, since the latter may be small and the former may be largely outside your control.  Forgive me if I am stating the obvious, but when an instance is "stopped," the physical host resources allocated to it are released once the OS shuts down -- it isn't merely stopped in place, ready to fire back up. It's assigned to a new physical host each time it's started, so there is a potential for variation in restart time related to the responsiveness of the EC2 control plane.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at AWS lambda ? (https://aws.amazon.com/lambda ).

Lambda supports node.js and will automatically manage the scaling of required worker infrastructure, depending on the number of requests. This will avoid your "one hour bill" problem. You only pay for used processing time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I had a chance to look at lambda. I am not sure if it can handle the complex procedure of launching a custom docker container.